# monotouch device only crash

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, xamarin.ios

I have an app which uses btouch'd bindings for WEPopover. You can find the bindings below with a SAMPLE application that works on both device *and* simulator:

https://github.com/anujb/monotouch-bindings

I am using that same dll in another app and it works on simulator but causes a crash on device:

Crash Log:

```
Hardware Model:      iPad2,1
Process:         MyApp [2905]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/31F6EA63-F5B5-49A4-B78B-7A0EDE39FF6E/MyApp.app/MyApp
Identifier:      MyApp
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2012-01-11 20:56:08.238 -0600
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.0.1 (9A405)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3088932c 0x30878000 + 70444
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x37d2af54 0x37cdd000 + 319316
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x37d23fe4 0x37cdd000 + 290788
3   MyApp                       0x009c8048 mono_handle_native_sigsegv (mini-exceptions.c:2249)
4   MyApp                       0x009f53c4 sigabrt_signal_handler (mini-posix.c:196)
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x37d35532 0x37cdd000 + 361778
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x37d2af54 0x37cdd000 + 319316
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x37d23fe4 0x37cdd000 + 290788
8   MyApp                       0x00b450c8 monoeg_g_logv (goutput.c:135)
9   MyApp                       0x00b4519c monoeg_assertion_message (goutput.c:155)
10  MyApp                       0x0099d080 mono_resolve_patch_target (mini.c:3179)
11  MyApp                       0x009bbf5c mono_aot_plt_resolve (aot-runtime.c:3134)
12  MyApp                       0x009ca640 mono_aot_plt_trampoline (mini-trampolines.c:768)
13  MyApp                       0x003fa930 generic_trampoline_aot_plt (mscorlib.dll.6.s:204591)
14  MyApp                       0x00ab3b6c mono_runtime_invoke (object.c:2757)
15  MyApp                       0x00a39894 create_exception_two_strings (exception.c:134)
16  MyApp                       0x00a3990c mono_exception_from_name_two_strings (exception.c:157)
17  MyApp                       0x009f6164 create_domain_objects (appdomain.c:177)
18  MyApp                       0x009f6430 mono_runtime_init (appdomain.c:261)
19  MyApp                       0x009a2b80 mini_init (mini.c:6584)
20  MyApp                       0x009ae728 mono_jit_init_version (driver.c:2233)
21  MyApp                       0x00996388 main (main.m:2423)
22  MyApp                       0x00008218 start + 32
```

Update: mtouch --logdev crash report:

```
Jan 11 21:16:55 unknown SpringBoard[15] <Warning>: Killing MyApp for termination assertion
Jan 11 21:17:00 unknown SpringBoard[15] <Warning>: Reloading application state for 'MyApp' as its modification date or path has changed
Jan 11 21:17:00 unknown SpringBoard[15] <Warning>: Reloading and rendering all application icons.
Jan 11 21:17:03 unknown SpringBoard[15] <Notice>: Posting 'com.apple.iokit.hid.displayStatus' notifyState=1
Jan 11 21:17:03 unknown SpringBoard[15] <Notice>: MultitouchHID: detection mode: 255->0 (deferring until bootloaded)
Jan 11 21:17:03 unknown SpringBoard[15] <Notice>: MultitouchHID: device bootloaded
Jan 11 21:17:03 unknown SpringBoard[15] <Notice>: MultitouchHID: detection mode: 0->0
Jan 11 21:17:03 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: set_crc_notification_state 0
Jan 11 21:17:07 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleKeyStore:cp_key_store_action(1)
Jan 11 21:17:07 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleKeyStore:Sending lock change
Jan 11 21:17:09 unknown UIKitApplication:MyApp[0xba5e][2965] <Notice>: Successfully received USB connection from MonoDevelop on port 10001.
Jan 11 21:17:09 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[2965] Builtin profile: container (sandbox)
Jan 11 21:17:09 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[2965] Container: /private/var/mobile/Applications/31F6EA63-F5B5-49A4-B78B-7A0EDE39FF6E [69] (sandbox)
Jan 11 21:17:14 unknown ReportCrash[2967] <Notice>: Formulating crash report for process MyApp[2965]
Jan 11 21:17:14 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Warning>: (UIKitApplication:MyApp[0xba5e]) Job appears to have crashed: Segmentation fault: 11
Jan 11 21:17:14 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Warning>: (UIKitApplication:MyApp[0xba5e]) Throttling respawn: Will start in 2147483642 seconds
Jan 11 21:17:14 unknown SpringBoard[15] <Warning>: Application 'MyApp' exited abnormally with signal 11: Segmentation fault: 11
Jan 11 21:17:14 unknown ReportCrash[2967] <Error>: Saved crashreport to /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MyApp_2012-01-11-211713_myipads-iPad.plist using uid: 0 gid: 0, synthetic_euid: 501 egid: 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known bug](http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=707) in the current stable release (5.0.*). It is fixed in the latest beta (5.1.1) - have in mind though that it is a beta and there are known regressions (for instance, if your application is big, it might not be possible to upload it to device).

You **may** have success working around the bug if you change the linker options (to link all assemblies)

Comment: Fiddling with the linker settings / compiling for release also did get it to launch sporadically. Let me know if you need me to file any additional comments in the bugzilla.

Answer (score 0):

> 8   MyApp                       0x00b450c8 monoeg_g_logv (goutput.c:135)

The mono runtime is trying to tell you something but that won't show up in the crash log (e.g. you might be running out of trampolines). Try running:

```
/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/mtouch --logdev
```

on a terminal window when running your application. The device log should contain the message and/or managed stack trace that will make this easier to diagnose.

Comment: Updated question above with crash log from mtouch --logdev

Comment: hmm... that's shorter than expected. Can you try this again with *Release*, i.e. not *Debug* ? and update the question if the log is different (e.g. more complete) ? thanks